# Using a DatePart inside a switch case statement

Tags: sql, switch-statement, datepart

I'm a beginner to SQL making a stored procedure with the goal of taking a specified time range and interval, and returning data within that time range grouped by the interval. For example, an input of a two week time range and 2 day interval will give 7 data points of performance.

In order to make the groupings I'm using a switch case for the interval unit and datepart to extract it for grouping. However, my procedure won't compile. Here is my code:

```
declare @interval int
declare @unit varchar(6)

set @interval=1
set @unit='year'

select
    case @unit
        when 'year' then datepart(year, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'month' then datepart(month, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'week' then datepart(week, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'day' then datepart(day, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'hour' then datepart(hour, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'minute' then datepart(minute, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
        when 'second' then datepart(second, CreateDate)/@interval*@interval
    end
from OrderInfoCustom
group by
    case @unit
        when 'year' then datepart(year, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'month' then datepart(month, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'week' then datepart(week, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'day' then datepart(day, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'hour' then datepart(hour, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'minute' then datepart(minute, CreateDate)/@interval
        when 'second' then datepart(second, CreateDate)/@interval
    end
```

This refuses to compile, giving this error (multiple times):

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 Column
>   'OrderInfoCustom.CreateDate' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

It seems the compiler does not recognize that CreateDate is part of the aggregate function, since it is within a switch-case? I'm not sure.

EDIT: I should include I am on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are grouping by an expression, so you can't use part of that expression in the selection.

If you use the exact same expression, it should work:

```
select
  case @unit
    when 'year' then datepart(year, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'month' then datepart(month, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'week' then datepart(week, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'day' then datepart(day, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'hour' then datepart(hour, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'minute' then datepart(minute, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'second' then datepart(second, CreateDate)/@interval
  end * @interval
from OrderInfoCustom
group by
  case @unit
    when 'year' then datepart(year, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'month' then datepart(month, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'week' then datepart(week, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'day' then datepart(day, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'hour' then datepart(hour, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'minute' then datepart(minute, CreateDate)/@interval
    when 'second' then datepart(second, CreateDate)/@interval
  end
```

You can also use a subquery:

```
select y * @interval
from (
  select
    case @unit
      when 'year' then datepart(year, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'month' then datepart(month, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'week' then datepart(week, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'day' then datepart(day, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'hour' then datepart(hour, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'minute' then datepart(minute, CreateDate)/@interval
      when 'second' then datepart(second, CreateDate)/@interval
    end as y
  from OrderInfoCustom
) x
group by y
```

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry for the stupid questions. Thank you, your help was much appreciated.